# Where should I place interface actions in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface

I have problem with bootstraping my angular application. I'm wondering, where should I place interface actions? Should I create special controller or maybe a service with these actions? For example: I want to create object responsible for showing alerts and call MyUiModule.showAlert(message) from any place within app.

Which approach is better - controller, service, something else?

Comment: Service! Controllers should deal with a specific aspect of the application that is only used in one place. A service is code that can be injected at any point via the Angular DI API.

Comment: It should be in a service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to use the `showAlert` functionality from any place within the app, the best place to put it is in service.

Now in any controller, where you want to avail this service, just inject it as dependency and call the method.

```
app.factory("MyUiModule", function() {
   var UiModule = {};
       UiModule.showAlert  = function(message) {
          // construct the interface to show the alert
          // It could be angular-ui modal window
       };

       return UiModule;
});
```

In your controller where you want to use it:

```
app.controller("MyController", function($scope, MyUiModule) {
  $scope.login = function() {
      MyUiModule.showAlert("Please enter the username");
  }
});
```